# Proper way to uninstall/update a font using Inno Setup?

Tags: fonts, inno-setup

We have designed a Font and now we need to uninstall that during setup phase of Inno Setup and in order to distribute an updated version. Here is the scenario:

- I can't replace the font file directly because the previously installed font file name (not the Fontface name) could could be anything, like My_Awesome_Font_1.1.ttf or just My_Awesome_Font.ttf or anything else in the fonts folder because there are several previous releases.
- The font maybe currently in use during setup by other applications.

I have seen [**FontInstall**](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=FontInstall) attribute, it recommends not to uninstall or replace a font:

> It's recommended that you use the flags onlyifdoesntexist and
>   uninsneveruninstall when installing fonts to the {fonts} directory.

But since this is a special situation being a font designer, we need to do it anyway.

I guess I'll need to use pascal scripting for that. Can anyone please provide a hint on the proper way to do that?

Comment: That warning is there because of that other applications can currently use that font. You can uninstall it if you want. Just the applications that used it can lose the formatting. Let's say I will use your font in my Word like document and you'll remove it. Then I'll lose my formatting and I'll be angry :-)

Comment: Any help on how to uninstall a font during installation?

Comment: I have opened an issue for this on innosetup github repository: https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/88

Comment: I wanted to analyse if that requested system restart breaks the font registration... Well, you were faster with your report.